# Using interpolation within Node.js EJS includes

Tags: node.js, include, express, ejs

My Express app is using EJS, and my views directory looks like this:

```
./views
  ./contents
    home.ejs
  ./includes
    header.ejs
    footer.ejs
  layout.ejs
```

I'm trying to load home.ejs in my layout.ejs view conditionally based on a local variable named `contents` in my routes/index.js. That file looks like this:

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Home', contents: 'home.ejs' });
};
```

Ideally I could simply write (in layout.ejs):

```
<% include '/contents' + contents %>
```

where the trailing "contents" is the local variable which contains the relative path to the body text to load.

But alas, it appears EJS always interprets the text following an `include` directive literally, and there is no chance for any interpolation magic to happen.

I've also tried to no avail:

```
<% function yieldContent(contents){ %>
  <% var contentPath = 'contents/' + contents; %>
  <% include contentPath %>
<% }; %>
<% loadContent(); %>
```

Does anyone have a creative solution for conditionally including a view based on a variable passed in routes?

Comment: +1, what's the point of include if it can't be dynamic? I don't get how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no way to do this kind of dynamic includes in EJS. It might break the separation of business logic and view.
The solution can be to rendering the subtemplate in the controller, and passing its content to the layout.

For rendering subtemplate in the controller use something like this:

```
var ejs = require('ejs'),
, fs = require('fs')
, home = ejs.render(fs.readFileSync("contents/home.ejs", "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the version 2 of EJS, the `include` function does it well. With it, includes are inserted at runtime so variables can be used as pathnames.

In this case, the solution may be :

```
<%- include('contents/' + contents) %>
```

The function can also have another argument if necessary :

```
<%- include('mypathname', {foo:"bar"}) %>
```

The pathname has to be relative to the template which calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this hasn't been implemented into ejs but, there is this discussion and pull request that offers the functionality.

https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

in your render function you can include `fs.readFileSync` and `__dirname`.

**Render your page with options like this**

```
res.render('pages/'+req.file,{file_get_contents:fs.readFileSync,__dirname:__dirname});
```

**Then you can use it in your `.ejs` page like this. This remains in server side.**

```
<% var products=JSON.parse(file_get_contents(__dirname+'/web/data/products.json','utf8')) %>
```

**You can print the data on client HTML like this.**

```
<%- JSON.stringify(products)%>
```

**Note : Using this method means you have `fs` included somewhere at the top of your script.**

```
var fs = require('fs')
```