# Unable to include dynamically created file within include statement using node.js, express and embedjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, include, ejs

I am trying to include an html file, whether .ejs or .html, but in a dynamically manner.

So for instance, in an extremely simple case, I want to call a file that either says either,
./views/nextdirectory/loggedin.ejs

```
<div class="loggedin">Hi <%= user.name %></div>
```

or ./views/nextdirextory/loggedout.ejs

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="login">Log In</a></li>
  <li><a href="signup">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
```

--

In my web.js file, I check if user is logged in and set a variable called loggedInOrNot that holds either ./nextdirectory/loggedin.ejs or ./nextdirectory/loggedout.ejs and call loggedInOrNot in the page.ejs file.

I know I can use an include statement as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014384/how-to-render-multiple-ejs-files-in-nested-form-in-node-js-and-express/17019406#17019406) however, I am unable to use a dynamically created variable with the include statement.

UPDATE:
so the answer is here. Didn't see this before posting my question, although I think it is more of a hack or fix than an appropriate application. Not sure how this may work as an application extends:
[Using interpolation within Node.js EJS includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804691/using-interpolation-within-node-js-ejs-includes?rq=1)

UPDATE:
 
Actually this doesn't work. HTML markup shows and not rendered.

UPDATE: 
So I finally got it to work. Just a simple mistake. had to add the hyphen as shown below:

```
<%- loggedInOrNot %>
```

Comment: I just notice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804691/using-interpolation-within-node-js-ejs-includes?rq=1, however it doesn't appear to answer the question except for "Not possible" is about as much as I get from that.

Comment: Okay I got it now. as the answer to the link in the above comment says, add a var requiring ejs, then prepend it to the fs statement. I add this to my response.render statement and it works.